# What is the idiomatic way to use props in component composing in reactjs

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs, architecture, react-native, idioms

Dear architects/design experts,

I'm using Alt Js to inject stores and actions to react native components. In this case some stored properties are not using in entire component tree, but only by some components which are in very deeper level.

For example *(Please refer to image)*: I have composed component `X` using `Y` and `Z` components. And injected an alt store called `P` to component `X` and passing it to component `Z` through component `Y` as a prop. In this case the `P` store is not using by component `Y`, but had to pass as a prop to `Y` because it needs to component `Z`

I feel like the prop requirement of component `Z` ruins the usage places of component `Y` because of that prop is really not using by `Y` in it self, just passing to `Z`. What is the idiomatic way to inject alt stores and pass props to child components without messing the code. Is there a way to pass props, inject alt stores to one specific place and use in every component without passing through entire component tree.

[image: Component composing layout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass down unexpected props by making each component pass down all of its props.

```
function ComponentX(props) {
  const { p } = props;
  // use p here
  return <ComponentY {...props} />;
}

function ComponentY(props) {
  // don't use props.p here
  return <ComponentZ {...props} />;
}

function ComponentZ(props) {
  const { p } = this.props;
  return <span>{p}</span>
}

render(
  <ComponentX p={true} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

However, if you're passing a store down through the components, then you might want to take a leaf from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)'s book and use [the context mechanism](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) instead.

Design a provider component which is initialized with the store (example comes directly from react-redux). In fact, you could almost definitely just use `react-redux` to pass your store down.

```
export default class Provider extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return { store: this.store }
  }
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.store = props.store
  }

  render() {
    return Children.only(this.props.children)
  }
}
```

Then wrap your top-most component in your provider and all it (and it's children) will be able to access the store through context.

```
function ComponentX(props, context) {
  const { foo } = context.store;
  return <div>{foo}</div>;
}

render(
  <Provider store={yourStore}>
    <ComponentX />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you want your components to be as isolated as possible. By writing one big component at the very top receiving all the props and passing them down you're tightly coupling all your components together.

In your example, your `<Z/>` component "depends" on the `<Y/>` component which in turn "depends" on the `<X/>` component connected to the store.

If you want to use your `<Z/>` component elsewhere, you will have to reproduce some similar hierarchy since it's not a "standalone" component, it's a *"component-that-depend-on-some-other-component-higher-connected-to-store"*.

I don't know Alt JS but in [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) this philosophy is to connect your component to the store as close as they need data. Any time you see yourself passing down props without using this props, it's a good indicator that you should connect your component to the store instead.

In your example, you could write something like:

***(pseudo code, I don't know Alt JS) : ***

```
<AltJS store={store}>  //let's say AltJs is a component that expose the store via context
    <X>
        <Y>
            <Z p={p received from store}/>
        </Y>
    </X>    
</AltJS/>
```

Comment: Connecting the component to the store is important, but first you need a mechanism to get the `store` to component `Z`. If you're thinking about the problem in terms of `react-redux` the asker wants a `<Provider />` not a `connect`.

Comment: I think he needs both. The `<Provider/>` to be able to access the `store` at a deep level and a mechanism to `connect` his deeper components to the store. But I agree `connect` is not mandatory here, the notion of `<Provider/>` is sufficient.